# Learning curve - Why does the train learning curve is flat?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, overfitting

I implemented a model in which I use Random Forest as classifier and I wanted to plot the learning curves for both training and test sets to decide what to do next in order to improve my model.

**Dataset details:**

107 radiomics feature extracted from 580 CT image.

The training dataset has 406 records.

The testing dataset has 174 records.

**The Code:**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[df.columns.difference(['label'])], 
                                                df['label'], 
                                                test_size=0.3, 
                                                random_state=42)

over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='auto')   #OverSampling Minority class
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
steps = [('over', over), ('model', clf)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
plot_learning_curves(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, pipeline,scoring='precision')
plt.show()
```

**My results are in the below image**
[image: Learning Curves]

I wonder why does the training Curve is flat? (Also other training metrics Curve are flat)

Is my model overfits?

Comment: If you notice the blue curve is at the max value of $1$ of the metric, which is also far from the other curve. Try to plot the blue curve separately, since the scale of the plot can make difficult to see its actual shape.